# What is the correct way to use the lang attribute with phonetic pronunciations (if at all)?

Tags: html, localization

Some languages have an accepted transliteration to Latin characters, such as Hindi, Russian or Japanese. For example, the Hindi for 'The man is eating' written in Devanagari script is 'आदमी खा रहा है।'. Transliterated, it would be 'Aadmi kha raha hai.' (or something similar; this approach is often used online, especially if people don't have access to a Hindi keyboard.)

In this case, we're using the Latin script but still writing Hindi, so it would be acceptable to mark up either variation using the `lang` attribute:

`<span lang="hi">आदमी खा रहा है।</span>` **or** `<span lang="hi">Aadmi kha raha hai.</span>`

My question then is about languages that are normally written in the Latin alphabet themselves, but might have phonetic guides for non-speakers/learners — either IPA or ad hoc pronunciation — is there any best practice in terms of giving it semantic meaning?

For example, in Irish if I were to say "The man is eating", I would say "Tá an fear ag ithe." I can mark this up as:

`<span lang="ga">Tá an fear ag ithe.</span>`

If I were to give a pronunciation guide for non-speakers, I might say *"Taw on far eg ih-he"*. The sentence isn't meaningless, (like 'lorem ipsum' text) but neither is the sentence in either English or Irish.

What is the correct use of language related attributes in HTML in this case, or is this use case just not covered currently by the specification?

Comment: Interesting to see Irish on SO :)

Comment: @Darragh Thought why not use an example close to home :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short version: if you want to specifically say it's written in the Latin alphabet, go for "hi-Latn" or "ga-Latn" for the examples you gave.

Long version:

[The W3C spec for the lang attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html) doesn't specifically mention this - it suggests some uses of this that depend on orthography (such as using it in order to render high-quality versions of the characters used), but some that don't (such as for search engines).

[RFC1766](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1766.txt), which specifies the format for the language tags, suggests that specialisations of tags may be used to represent "script variations, such as az-arabic and az-cyrillic". There's more about the script subtag [in this article on the W3C site](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/#script), and a bit extra in [the later RFC5646](http://www.inter-locale.com/ID/rfc5646.html#script). That one points to an [ISO standard list of script names](http://unicode.org/iso15924/iso15924-codes.html), and in that list the script you'd want is "Latn" as they're romanised forms of other scripts.

(This doesn't cover things like specifying how you did the transliteration, though, for languages which may have more than one standard e.g. Chinese in Latin script using Wade-Giles versus pinyin.)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting on the `-Latn` suffix. Though the distinction I was trying to make vs Hindi is that Irish is Latin by default: So when transliterating Hindi, it is spelled phonetically in the new script and still considered 'Hindi'. Phonetic spelling of a language already in Latin, like Irish (or French/German/etc) renders out something that couldn't be considered either language. Thanks for the links though, I've some new homework to read up on :)

Comment: As a bonus: I'm not sure how standard the phonetic spelling you gave for the Irish text is, but http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry has variant tags you could use if it were in IPA (ga-fonipa) or X-SAMPA (ga-fonxsamp).

Comment: Completely, 100% not standard :) Wow, that's interesting as were I using IPA standards, that would be perfect. I see also from that page that there are `Zyyy ` and `Zzzz` variants (for 'undetermined script' and 'uncoded script' respectively) which may also be of use for non-standard variants.

Comment: Warning: though this is correct, on some e-book platforms this code will trigger odd font changes; see http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=274838.

Answer (score 2):

For most practical purposes, it does not matter, since browsers, search engines, and other relevant programs generally ignore `lang` attributes. The attributes may affect the choice of font, but only when the page itself does not suggest fonts (which is rare). Some speech browsers recognize a few values for `lang` and adapt their functionality accordingly. And if you open an HTML document in MS Word, it recognizes the `lang` markup and applies language-specific spelling tools. But all this is rather limited and rarely matters much. Moreover, in these cases, only the simplest types of language codes are recognized.

In principle, it is possible to indicate the writing system (“script”), such as Latin vs. Devanagari, and the transliteration or transcription system that has been used. This has been described in [BCP 47](http://www.w3.org/International/core/langtags/rfc3066bis.html). But for the most of it, it’s guidelines for implementors, not something you could use here and now.

For example, you can write `<span lang="hi-Latn">Aadmi kha raha hai.</span>` to indicate that the content is in Hindi but written in Latin letters. And there is, in principle at least, a way to indicate which of the competing romanization systems has been used. I don’t think any web-related software recognizes `lang="hi-Latn"`; programs might even fail to recognize it even if they recognize `lang="hi"`.

So you can use detailed values for `lang`, but it’s not of much use. Using simple markup like `lang="hi"` for a any *major* fragment in another language (say, a sentence or more) is good practice, though not much more. Before spending too much time on it, consider what practical benefits you could expect. For example, if you consider using a client-side hyphenator like [hyphenate.js](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/), then `lang` markup becomes essential; but then you need to check out the expectations of that software, rather than just general specifications.

A word of warning: I have seen odd results when using `lang="ru"` for Russian written in Latin letters. The reason is that browsers may switch to their idea of “font for Russian”, causing a mix of fonts. But the simple remedy is to make some consistent font settings for all of your texts, overriding browser defaults, in cases like this.

Strings like “Taw on far eg ih-he” cannot be meaningfully classified as being in some language. If you use language markup, use `lang=""` (with empty string as value), since this is the defined way of explicitly indicating that the language is not indicated!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could supply an empty lang attribute! Regarding the fact that search engines ignore lang attributes — would you have a link for that? I always thought that Google et al used it for their advanced settings (display results in French, etc.)

Comment: It is common to say that search engines use `lang` attributes, but there is no evidence on that. Tests suggest that they have no effect. Unofficial statements from people associated by search engines say that `lang` attributes are too unreliable, often plain wrong e.g. because some authoring systems emit `lang="en"` without asking the author. Search engines can pretty well guess the language from the content, and they do.

Comment: The lang attribute is important to accessibility and is a WCAG 2.0 requirement. Screen readers use the value of the lang attribute to determine the correct voice and phonetic engine to use during playback.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into marking it up as [`<ruby>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-ruby-element).

For example:

```
<ruby lang="hi">आदमी<rt>Aadmi</rt> खा<rt>kha</rt> रहा<rt>raha</rt> है।<rt>hai</rt></ruby>
```

Comment: Admittedly I’m not an expert but this looks like the answer. Could the downvoter please comment? (Maybe it’s just about the form – I agree that the answer could provide a bit more details, rather than just a link)

Comment: The answer has nothing to do with the question, which was about language markup.

Comment: @Jukka But isn’t `<ruby>` *about* language markup / pronunciation guides?

Comment: @Jukka So? `<ruby>` is for marking up text with phonetic guides. Click the link?

Comment: :) Thanks @deceze — it was looking into the `ruby` tag that had me arrive at this question to begin with! While I was looking into it, was thinking that the `<rt>` tag can provide secondard information, but it is unclear what this information is — e.g. translation / simplification / transliteration. We need to add semantics somehow in order to clarify that. So if I had a `<rt>` tag for my Irish pronunciation example above, how would you add in that semantic meaning? The main `<ruby>` tag you could give a lang attribute of 'ga', but I don't know what you'd then do with `<rt>`.

Comment: @another The `<rt>` element wouldn't receive a `lang` attribute at all, because it already signifies "this is a phonetic guide".

Comment: @deceze But if an element doesn't receive a lang attribute, then doesn't it inherit from it's parent? — So taking on the 'ga'? From my understanding of the spec, it doesn't imply that the `<rt>` element is a phonetic guide, merely *some* secondary information. They give an example of `<rb>WWW</rb>` with `<rt>World Wide Web</rt>` http://www.w3.org/TR/ruby/#simple-ruby1

Comment: @another True... but maybe you're simply overthinking this? :-) Whoever is parsing this later and *understands `<ruby>`* will probably know not to treat the secondary information as `'ga'`, or at least not literally, because ruby annotation are typically phonetic guides.

Comment: @deceze, of course I'm over-thinking it, but that was the whole question! ;) I would say that 1) Lang attributes can have an affect on SEO, screen-readers, etc. currently, without any user actively parsing the document 2) If content is marked up correctly, it should degrade gracefully and not rely on someone understanding the tag (for instance, if an agent doesn't understand the `<rt>` tag, the text will be displayed inline in the browser) and 3) as per the spec, it might be in the original language and this is a valid use case. Thanks for the discussion on it though, it's clarifying.